# WebGL rendering a lot of objects - performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

I'm working with [ChemDoodle library](https://web.chemdoodle.com) for rendering complex chemical structures. Everything works fine, but with big molecules (about 20k atoms) it's working quite slow. I don't have much experience in graphics, but I think it might me because each atom is rendering independently - every time it's rerendering, it has to iterate over array of atoms (it should be buffered).

My idea was to create some structure, that would be calculated on init time and when render, only camera would change it's position.  I don't need to manipulate with atoms, only use mouse to rotate/move whole molecule. Is something like this even possible and would it improve performance?

I would appreciate info if it's possible (or some other suggestions), ideally in pure WebGL, without ThreeJS..

Comment: Did you look at the API of ChemDoodle? Have you tried any of it? Can you show some code of how you're doing it right now? Basically: if you can allocate a huge vertex buffer array and draw your object in one call - 20k times some spheres should be no problem at all.

Comment: I studied whole API, even playing with source code of library (debugging and benchmarking). 
You can check http://pastebin.com/VBaHH0yJ, it's basically copied from demo page. 
And this is the molecule I try to render - http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=1CQE

Comment: Yeah that's still no actual code... What about [_Mesh](https://web.chemdoodle.com/docs/api/#_Mesh): seems like there are methods to retrieve and set the vertex data arrays -> iterate over all your meshes, collect their data in one big indexed array, create a new type (i.e. AtomCollection) as an instance of `_Mesh`, set its data and render it.

Comment: for 20k objects you probably need to combine meshes. [Otherwise here's some techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg).